# NullReferenceExceeption when making async call, but not when making sync call

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Blazor server-side app, .NET5, EF Core 5.0.7

I have a Blazor component that injects an application database context, and then tries to load some data when the component initialises. This code is in a `.razor.cs` partial class file...

```cs
    [Inject]
    private ApplicationDbContext Context { get; set; }

    private List<User> _feeEarners = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() =>
      _feeEarners = await Context.Users.ToListAsync();
```

I've done this loads and loads of times, and it's always worked fine, but for some reason, the line of code above throws a NRE.

I've put a breakpoint inside `OnInitializedAsync` and checked in the debugger, and `Context` is not null, and I can expand the `Users` property and see the results, so I can't see what could be null here.

If I change that line of code so it's not async...

```
_feeEarners = Context.Users.ToList();
```

...then it works fine.

Anyone any idea what's going on here? As I said, I have done this loads of times, and it's always worked before.

Thanks

P.S. As often happens with Blazor, the stack trace is extremely unhelpful...

```
MySite.Web.Areas.Cases.Pages.Note.BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder __builder)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HandleException(Exception exception)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessPendingRender()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToRenderQueue(int componentId, RenderFragment renderFragment)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.StateHasChanged()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HandleException(Exception exception)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderRootComponentAsync(int componentId, ParameterView initialParameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.CreateInitialRenderAsync(Type componentType, ParameterView initialParameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.RenderComponentAsync(Type componentType, ParameterView initialParameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext+<>c__11<TResult>+<<InvokeAsync>b__11_0>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.StaticComponentRenderer.PrerenderComponentAsync(ParameterView parameters, HttpContext httpContext, Type componentType)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ComponentRenderer.PrerenderedServerComponentAsync(HttpContext context, ServerComponentInvocationSequence invocationId, Type type, ParameterView parametersCollection)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ComponentRenderer.RenderComponentAsync(ViewContext viewContext, Type componentType, RenderMode renderMode, object parameters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.ComponentTagHelper.ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.<RunAsync>g__Awaited|0_0(Task task, TagHelperExecutionContext executionContext, int i, int count)
MySite.Web.Areas.General.Pages.Areas_General_Pages__Host.<ExecuteAsync>b__14_1() in _Host.cshtml
+
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync()
MySite.Web.Areas.General.Pages.Areas_General_Pages__Host.ExecuteAsync() in _Host.cshtml
+
  Layout = null;
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, string contentType, Nullable<int> statusCode)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext<TFilter, TFilterAsync>(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Is this code in a separate code file or inside the `@code{}` block on the razor component file?

Comment: @gunr2171 In the `@code{}` block. Updated the question, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: In that case (and humor me, this is mostly a guess) instead of the property with the attribute, put `@inject ApplicationDbContext Context` at the top of the file.

Comment: Post (the top of) the stacktrace. It can't really be this line, it probably just happens elsewhere during this `await`. Any not null-safe items in the markup section? Blazor will render your page with the empty _feeEarners. Look for FirstOrDefault() or similar.

Comment: @gunr2171 Sorry, I answered you too quickly. The code isn't actually in a `@code{}` block in the `.razor` file, it's in a `.razor.cs` partial class file. I amended my question

Comment: @HenkHolterman Sadly, the stack trace is extremely unhelpful. I added it, but as you can see, it doesn't give anything useful (as far as I can see)

Comment: If you step through the code when you've broken, where does it take you?

Comment: @DreamingOfSleep Just jumps to the `_Host.cshtml` file. Like the stack trace, it's really unhelpful

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel - but what is missing in the trace is OnInitializedAsync. The NRE happens in the render, hence in your mark-up. Reduce it to a [mre], you will most likely find it yourself. I still bet on a  FirstOrDefault().

Comment: @Avrohom Yisroel,  it shouldn't be hard to solve your issue... Why don't you post a minimal repro of your code ? Why do we have to speak in riddle and assumptions. ? Do you use DB Context Factory (services.AddDbContextFactory<ContactContext>) ? If not, you should. Perhaps the issue stems from not using that feature.

Comment: Breaking from the current discussion for a moment, I normally see errors like this when there's something actually wrong in the "markup", not usually in the @code section.

Maybe there's something on the page that's assuming the list of _feeEarners isn't empty?

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel check this repo out. You can see the difference on the "Fetch Async" and the "Fetch Sync" pages.
[github repo](https://github.com/kwhv23/MinRepro-Async-Render-NRE)

The async one causes a NRE when it tries to get the first user from the list, the sync one doesn't.

Is this possibly related to your issue?

Comment: ServerPrerendered

Comment: @BrianParker Agreed. This "problem" probably only exists with ServerPrerendered set.

Comment: @BrianParker - and how would ServerPrerendered be different? It should follow the same logic.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Isn't there a different "path" that's followed with ServerPrerendered? I thought it would do a pre-render, then call OnInit, then render again? I could be mistaken.

EDIT: Actually, I tested on that repo I made with render-mode set to "Server" and it had the same problem... Nevermind.

Comment: @F0urL1ghts - there are a few differences (JavaScript) but with properly written markup it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really an answer, but there's no other place for a long comment with code.

The primary difference between:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() 
   => _feeEarners = await Context.Users.ToListAsync();
```

and

```
protected override Task OnInitializedAsync() 
   {
_feeEarners = Context.Users.ToList();
return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Is that in the async version there is likely to be a yield before `_feeEarners` is actually populated, and thus an initial render of the component when `_feeEarners` is empty.  The problem is therefore likely to be in the UI code - the code we don't see in the question.

Here's the relevant ComponentBase code for reference. `OnInitializedAsync` is called and the returned task is assigned to a local variable.  If it yields, `StateHasChanged` is called and it's awaited.  The Renderer gets thread time to run its queue and render the component.

```
        private async Task RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
        {
           OnInitialized();
            var task = OnInitializedAsync();

            if (task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion && task.Status != TaskStatus.Canceled)
            {
                // Call state has changed here so that we render after the sync part of OnInitAsync has run
                // and wait for it to finish before we continue. If no async work has been done yet, we want
                // to defer calling StateHasChanged up until the first bit of async code happens or until
                // the end. Additionally, we want to avoid calling StateHasChanged if no
                // async work is to be performed.
                StateHasChanged();

                try
                {
                    await task;
                }
                catch // avoiding exception filters for AOT runtime support
                {
                    // Ignore exceptions from task cancellations.
                    // Awaiting a canceled task may produce either an OperationCanceledException (if produced as a consequence of
                    // CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()) or a TaskCanceledException (produced as a consequence of awaiting Task.FromCanceled).
                    // It's much easier to check the state of the Task (i.e. Task.IsCanceled) rather than catch two distinct exceptions.
                     if (!task.IsCanceled)
                     {
                        throw;
                     }
                }

                // Don't call StateHasChanged here. CallOnParametersSetAsync should handle that for us.
            }

            await CallOnParametersSetAsync();
        }
```

Comment: `private List<User> _feeEarners = new();` , it is never `null`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman.  Thanks, "Answer" amended.

Comment: Your answer led me to the problem. It was nothing to do with `_feeEarners` per se, more that setting that must have fired `StateHasChanged`, and something (seemingly unrelated) in the markup was referring to a variable that hadn't been set. Thanks very much, this was very instructive!

Comment: @HenkHolterman agreed, but it's hard to explain why in a comment.  I did say "this is not an answer, but a long comment with code".  Anyway it fortuitously lead to the answer!